# How to have fixed scrolling in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how to have fixed scrolling in a webpage like what's used here: http://manifeste.hermes.com/en_WW/?

It looks like when you scroll it automatically smooth scrolls to the next div. I assume there's some JavaScript involved, but it's beyond my knowledge how to do this.

Can anyone show me how this is done?

Comment: It uses a combination of binding a callback function to a scroll event using jquery(window).on("scroll",function(){}); and probably using animate to move the divs into view.

Comment: imho while this looks great its not very usable.

Comment: The mentioned site is fact making use of [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this nice, lightweight javascript plugin [alvarotrigo fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)
they have a nice explanation and examples on the github page.

[fullPage.js Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!